# PowerShell gci -Path C:\ -exclude "Windows" -Directory shows no directories

Tags: powershell-4.0

These are my root level directories:

> gci -Path C:\ -Directory

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                  
d----          1/9/2020  10:35 AM            DevResources                                                                                          
d----         9/12/2018   7:13 AM            inetpub                                                                                               
d----         8/22/2013  10:52 AM            PerfLogs                                                                                              
d-r--        12/11/2019   9:30 AM            Program Files                                                                                         
d----         10/7/2019   2:50 PM            Program Files (x86)                                                                                   
d----         10/3/2018   7:11 AM            Projects                                                                                              
d----         8/22/2019   1:08 PM            SymCache                                                                                              
d----         1/20/2020  10:57 AM            temp                                                                                                  
d-r--        12/11/2019   8:58 AM            Users                                                                                                 
d----         8/22/2019   2:22 PM            Windows                                                                                               
d----         7/31/2019  10:43 PM            Zabbix
```

but when I run:

> gci -Path C:\ -exclude "Windows" -Directory

I get no results at all. It seems easy, but I don't see what's wrong.

I'm using the results of this to pipe into another command to find the largest files.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.  It seems like a bug.  It works in subdirectories.

```
gci -path c:\windows -directory -exclude winsxs
```

It gives a strange message in osx in 6.2.3:

```
gci -path / -directory -exclude var

gci : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gci -path / -directory -exclude var
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Or this way in windows ps 5.1 - 7:

```
dir Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\ -exclude windows

dir : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:2
+  dir Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\ -exclude windows
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Here's a workaround, but only for powershell 6 and 7:

```
get-item c:\ | get-childitem -exclude windows
```

Comment: I thought the excludes had to be in quotes.  Would the quotes make a difference on your query?

Comment: @NealWalters nope, you only needs quotes if there's a space